# updation of copied database

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application the database is read only .As i am using preexisting sqlite database to create database on the device.My question in my next update i would like to change or update the contents of the database how to achieve that. from this class i am copying the database, as far as the code goes i think when i publish the update on play store the updated database wouldn't get copied as it is already there.

```
public class Setupdb extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "camprep.sqlite";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

    private static Setupdb mDBConnection;


public Setupdb(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 3);
    this.myContext=context;
    DB_PATH="/data/data/"
            + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/databases/";
    Log.e(DB_NAME, DB_PATH);
}
public static synchronized Setupdb getDBAdapterInstance(Context context) {
    if (mDBConnection == null) {
        mDBConnection = new Setupdb(context);
    }
    return mDBConnection;
} 

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
            Log.e("db","exist");
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {
            // By calling following method
            // 1) an empty database will be created into the default system path of your application
            // 2) than we overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                Log.e("calling", "copy");
                copyDataBase(); 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }





}
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false; 
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
        // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
        // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush(); 
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
} 


    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close(); 
    } 

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


}
```

}

Comment: You might consider switching to using `SQLiteAssetHelper`, which has a framework for updating databases in the manner that you describe: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: You dont have to check whether database exists, increment the database version and add the things in OnUpgrade , if Oncreate is called just copy it

Comment: @nandeesh sir, as can see i am not using oncreate and onupgrade in the db creation

Comment: As onupgrade is called once when db version is higher then current , so in onupgrade mycontext.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME) will this work